# Memoryleak when using Geocode

Tags: delphi, gmlib

Every time I use

```
GMGeoCode.Geocode(lAddress);
```

Where lAddress is an existing address found in a database, I get a memoryleak
If I do everything else on the for except the      GMGeoCode.Geocode(lAddress);  the leak isn't there

Is there something that I should free after calling Geocode?

Comment: not shure about, https://code.google.com/p/gmlibrary/issues/detail?id=13

Comment: How do you detect the memory leak? What is leaked? Are you using the full verson of FastMM so that you can get good diagnostics of the leak.

Comment: If the comment of bummi is not your solution, please, say me

Comment: I am using EurekaLog 7 to detect the leak

Comment: @cadetill   I am using v 1.1.0 final - are there any updates for that that I have missed?

Comment: @bummi  I am not sure either. The version I use should be the latest and I can't find any updates to it in the SVN

Comment: I can't find anything newer too, maybe you can get more information via the blog http://www.cadetill.com/gmlib_en/

Answer (score 1):

The 1.1.0 release don't have this bug fixed. You need to download the last version in SVN repository or change the destructor of TAddressComponentsList in unit GMGeoCode by this line with this:

```
destructor TAddressComponentsList.Destroy;
begin
  if Assigned(FAddrComponents) then FreeAndNil(FAddrComponents);

  inherited;
end;
```

Regards

Comment: That made quite a difference

if Assigned(FAddrComponents) then TObjectList.Create;
and
if Assigned(FAddrComponents) then FreeAndNil(FAddrComponents);